# FB.api SOMETIMES doesn't return email

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following method:

```
function CompleteFbData() {
    FB.api('/me', 'get', {fields: 'id,name,email,birthday'}, function(response) {
        $("#profile_full_name").val(response.name);
        $("#profile_email").val(response.email);
        $("#profile_telephone").focus()
        $("#loginbutton").remove();
    });
}
```

This **should** return me id, name, email and birthday from my user's facebook account. However, it sometimes will get me only the id and name.

Eg1:

[returns email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBI92.png)

Eg2:

[doesn't return email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQxSy.png)

Since it's important that I always get the user email for my application, is there a way I can ensure it will always get the email?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: I understand that a Facebook account doesn't necessarily have an e-mail associated to it, so I must change my application. 
However, in the examples I printed, the accounts used were created by myself, both have e-mails associated to each one of the. Still it did not return the email in one of them. 
Note: this happens a lot, sometimes it returns sometimes won't return. Couldn't understand why and when it happens.

Comment: you cannot be sure to always get an email. not all users have an email on facebook.

Comment: @luschn I understand that, however those prints were accounts that I created myself and both were created with emails. I'm gonna add that to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook api requests don't return email if the email isn't valid. Do both the emails you have used for the separate accounts have valid @ addresses? also has the email been verified via facebooks verification email?

Try this and if it works..woohoo!

Comment: I used [10minutemail](https://10minutemail.net/) which generates a random email everytime, so the @org can change. *I verified via verification email both times*

Comment: It may recognise this as spam as it may be blacklisted on facebooks side. Try via a gmail, hotmail email etc. This way you could know whether or not it is due to the email address generator.

Comment: I thought it could something like that, but I did think Facebook could block certain @ addresses. I will make tests with gmail and so on. However this makes testing really annoying, since these big mail companies require authentication steps themselves, like phone numbers.

Comment: I agree with it being annoying but it's their security I guess, what you could do is to loop the request until it pulls back an email. Store the first email, attempt to pull the second until a value is returned?

Comment: I made a [FB](https://imgur.com/a/5AU8vDY) account using a [GMAIL](https://imgur.com/a/gD0gKDY) account, yet it [dind't return me the email](https://imgur.com/a/IQU43W1)

Comment: Have you made sure the email you're trying to a has its permission set to granted? Check the settings on the account as you may be hiding the email (weird but its worth a go)

Comment: You mean the permissions from account I created on Facebook? I dind't know you could opt out of allowing sites to get you email when you login on them, using Fb

Comment: When you log into facebook, check your permissions that your email address is public and if not, flick the switch! It may then allow you to pull it. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Sorry I took this long to reply. We treated the user as logged by the token FB provided and moved on. Unfortunately, I no longer have the code to keep investigating.

Comment: @doofz Sorry I couldn't be more help!